# Require permissions to create contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I'm using a contract as a template, of sorts, such that it is not deployed immediately with the rest of my contracts, but may be instantiated (multiple times) by a "contract factory," call it the Manager. So, for example, some contract or user calls a function Manager.createNewContract(data), which then creates a new Contract and saves its address in an array for further use....like this:

```
contract C { ... }

contract Manager {
    address[] contracts;

    constructor() { ... }

    function createNewContract(...) {
        C c = new C(...);
        contracts.push(address(c));
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to impose the restriction that only the Manager may create a new C, and that C should throw if any other address attempts to instantiate, like the onlyOwner modifier from the Ownable contract (open-zeppelin). Is there any way to do this? I'm thinking something like a permissions contract that is inherited by C, but then each C gets its own copy so there's no central governing system. If anything needs to be clarified, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate on @smarx's answer, there's nothing you can do to prevent someone from copying code and deploying it, so you have to focus on the interactions.

> you can consider only the contracts created by createNewContract to be "valid."

In practical terms, you might do something like this:

```
contract Manager is Ownable {

    address[] public contracts;
    mapping(address => bool) public isTrusted;

    constructor() { ... }

    modifier onlyTrustedContracts {
        require(isTrusted[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

    function createNewContract(...) onlyOwner {
        C c = new C(...);
        contracts.push(address(c));
        isTrusted[c] = true;
    }

    // Now you can guard access.

    function sensitive() onlyTrustedContracts ... {}
}
```

Obviously, too many loose ends to actually compile, but I hope it's illustrative.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Having a concrete example definitely helped clear it up in my head. Thank you!

Comment: Gotta spread the love. And reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly put permissions on `createNewContract`, but you can't put any meaningful permissions in C itself. Anyone could just copy/paste the code and remove that check. But there's no reason to care; you can consider only the contracts created by `createNewContract` to be "valid."